# Traveling salesman nodes count formula

Tags: nodes

Having trouble finding formula for **TSP** nodes count.
Lets say, we have an asymmetrical adjacency matrix with 4 cities.

```
matrix = {{0,1,2,3},{4,0,5,6},{7,8,0,9},{10,11,12,0},};
```

In excercise 5x5 matrix total nodes count is given, which is 41.

Every next tree level has n-1 possible next nodes to look for.
Another thing is that from last city, the path should end in first city. 
For example: [0,2,1,3,0].
[image: 5x5 Matrix nodes]
As it is seen in picture that every level has n-1 possible routes left.

Comment: Can you explain your specific question? What do you mean total node count?

Comment: Total node count would be the amount of nodes that greedy solution algorithm has work through to find best solution.
Added illustrative image.

Comment: As you can see from top, that question was about nodes count formula for this general solution. The program is already finished written and works with BSF cutting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you're trying to figure out the number of nodes in the tree. The top is 1, the next row has (n-1), the next has (n-1)(n-2), and so on until the bottom which is (n-1)(n-2)...2. So you're going to sum these up:

1 + (n-1) + (n-1)(n-2) + (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + ... + (n-1)(n-2)...2

This series is [OEIS 000248](http://oeis.org/A000248)